# LibGDX - get currently rendered screen as a matrix of RGB values

Tags: java, libgdx

In the middle of a game, I'd like to have access to the pixels being currently displayed on the screen as a matrix (or really several matrices) of RGB values. Is there an easy command to access this?

Comment: The class [ScreenUtils](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/ScreenUtils.html) has a few methods, which return the current `FrameBuffer` as `byte[]`, `PixMap` or even `TextureRegion`. I guess thats what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the code from [official LibGDX wiki[(https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Taking-a-Screenshot)

```
    byte[] pixels = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixels(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferHeight(), true);

    Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getBackBufferHeight(), Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
    BufferUtils.copy(pixels, 0, pixmap.getPixels(), pixels.length);

    //Your logic here

    pixmap.dispose();
```

Then you can get desired pixel by using [Pixmap](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.html) method:

```
    getPixel(int x, int y)
```

or just iterate over all pixels by using loop as following

```
    for(int w = 0; w < pixmap.getWidth(); w++)
        for(int h = 0; h < pixmap.getHeight(); h++)
            getPixel(w, h);
```

---

Remember that pixmap needs to be disposed. List of objects that need to be dispose you will find [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management)